# Ich will wissen was genau mit dem Satz gemeint ist. "Wir erwarten Sie schon"

Tags: meaning

Ich habe den Satz im E-Mail eines künftigen Arbeitgebers gesehen. Sie warten für mich? Sie erwarten dass ich da bin?

Answer (score 2):

Das ist eine feststehende Formel.

- Wir erwarten Sie schon. — Wir freuen uns schon auf den Tag, an dem Sie endlich kommen.

Answer (score 2):

Das Wort *»erwarten«* ist ein Verb, und es bedeutet, dass deine zukünftigen Arbeitgeber hoffen, dass du zu Ihnen kommst. Das Wort stammt zwar sprachgeschichtlich von *»warten«* ab, aber die ursprüngliche Bedeutung von *»warten«* ist nicht *»Zeit verstreichen lassen bis ein Ereignis eintritt«* sondern *»aufmerksam sein«.* Daher sagt man auch, wenn man den funktionierenden Motor eines Autos pflegt und vorsorglich alte Teile gegen neue austauscht, dass man den Motor *wartet.*

> Der Mechaniker wartet den Motor.

Das sagt man, weil man aufmerksam ist während man mit dem Motor beschäftigt ist.

Das Wort *»erwarten«* hängt in seiner Bedeutung schon mit dem Verstreichen von Zeit zusammen, drückt aber auch Hoffnung aus.

> Ich habe dich schon sehnsüchtig erwartet.

Wenn man etwas erwartet, hofft man, dass das Ereignis, welches das Warten beendet, eintritt. Das Wort bedeutet aber nicht, dass die, die warten, ungeduldig sind. Sie sind damit einverstanden, dass eine gewisse Zeit verstreichen muss, aber sie werden sich trotzdem freuen, wenn das *erwartete* Ereignis eintritt.

Man kann das Wort *»erwarten«* aber auch dann verwenden, wenn man (fast) mit Sicherheit davon ausgeht, dass ein bestimmtes Ereignis eintreten wird:

> Nachdem der Chemiker das Gemisch erhitzt hatte, erwartete er einen lauten Knall, aber es verbrannte nur mit einem leisen Zischen.

Comment: Diese Antwort diskutiert zwar ausführlich das Verb "erwarten", aber ich hätte gedacht, dass der Fragesteller größere Schwierigkeiten mit dem Wort "schon" hat. Vielleicht irre ich mich aber auch, denn leider hat der Fragesteller keine Hinweise diesbezüglich gegeben. "Erwarten" kann m.E. einfach im Wörterbuch nachschlagen. Bei "schon" dagegen kann Unsicherheit bestehen, ob es hier als Adverb oder als Modalpartikel verwendet wurde.

Comment: @RHa: Das Wort *»schon«* kommt nur im Titel der Frage vor. Im eigentlichen Text der Frage wird das Wort überhaupt nicht verwendet. Die beiden Fragen nehmen jedoch eindeutig Bezug auf *»warten«* und *»erwarten«.*

Answer (score 1):

In this case "schon" means "already". They are waiting for you *already*. It is just a friendly phrase meaning they are looking forward to your coming.

Comment: Warum antwortest du in einer Fremdsprache, von der du nicht weißt, ob der Fragesteller sie spricht? Er hat auf Deutsch gefragt, daher solltest du auch auf Deutsch antworten.

Comment: Dass der Fragesteller "Sie warten für mich" als mögliche Bedeutung angegeben hat, weist allerdings darauf hin, dass er Englischkenntnisse hat, denn dieser Satz macht so hier keinen Sinn und ist vermutlich eine wörtliche Übersetzung von "They are waiting for me".